# How to bring a job to foreground and then disable job control in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, job-control

I have a program running in a terminal window. I wish to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut from suspending the process.

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the command `fg && set +m` unfortunately disables job control only after the process has finished. I could use `set +m` before I start the process, but my question is about the situation where I have already started the process and I need to disable job control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Basic solution

> I wish to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut from suspending the process.

For this you don't need to disable job control. Tell the terminal driver not to send SIGTSTP upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
stty susp ''
```

If you have already started the process, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, run `stty susp ''` (from now on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will not be special), then run `fg`.

To restore the usual meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
stty susp ^Z
```

For convenience you can compact these to a single line. Just after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, i.e. when the process is stopped, invoke:

```
stty susp ''; fg; stty susp ^Z
```

If this doesn't work for you, keep reading.

---

#### Possible problem, adjusted solution

In general programs may configure the terminal by themselves, so (depending on the program) it may happen that after you `stty susp ''; fg`, the program configures the terminal back (in a way equivalent to `stty susp ^Z`). To outsmart such program you can run `stty susp ''` from another terminal, yet addressing the original terminal, while the program is running. This is how:

1. In the original terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the program.
2. Invoke `tty`. The output will be like `/dev/pts/6` or `/dev/tty4`.
3. `fg` the program, give it a second.
4. In another terminal run `</dev/… stty susp ''`, where `/dev/…` is the exact output you got from `tty` in the original terminal.

---

#### Notes

- When "converting" of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to SIGTSTP is disabled after `stty susp ''`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will cause a byte `0x1A` (often denoted as `^Z`) reach whatever reads from the terminal (in your case: the program in question). This does not happen normally (and after `stty susp ^Z`), when the terminal intercepts this byte and "converts" it to SIGTSTP.

  For you this means that if the user tries <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then there will be no SIGTSTP (the behavior you want), but instead there will be *input* which in general may cause some (possibly unwanted) reaction of the program.
- There is also `stty -isig` that disables checking of input characters against the special control characters: INTR (usually `^C`), QUIT (usually `^\`) and SUSP (usually `^Z`, the question is about exactly this); `stty isig` enables them. See `man 1 stty`.

Comment: The command `stty susp ''; fg` did not work for me. Running `</dev/pts/0 stty susp ''` from a another terminal, as suggested, did work.